# Dokan Marketplace store link in single product page

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, wp-user-query

I use this this way to display product **store link with [vendor_shop_name] shortcode in custom product page.**

```
/*Shortcode [vendor_shop_name] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55364574/display-dokan-vendor-name-and-total-sales-on-woocommerce-single-product-pages*/
add_shortcode('vendor_shop_name', 'vendor_shop_name_function');
function vendor_shop_name_function() {
    global $product;
    $seller = get_post_field('post_author', $product->get_id());
    $author  = get_user_by('id', $seller);
    $vendor = dokan()->vendor->get($seller);
    $store_info = dokan_get_store_info($author->ID);
    
    if (!empty($store_info['store_name'])) {
        ?>
            <?php printf('<span class="vendorpage"><a href=" %s">in this store</a></span>', $vendor->get_shop_url(), $vendor->get_shop_name()); ?>
        <?php
    }
}
```

it works. But my problem is that **store link appear before header. I can not put it where I want.** Can anyone help me please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shortcodes should only ever `return` content, never `echo` or `printf()` it.

From the [`add_shortcode()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_shortcode/):

> Note that the function called by the shortcode should *never* produce an output of any kind. Shortcode functions should *return* the text that is to be used to replace the shortcode. Producing the output directly will lead to unexpected results.

So your code should look more like this.

```
add_shortcode('vendor_shop_name', 'vendor_shop_name_function');
function vendor_shop_name_function() {
    global $product;
    $seller = get_post_field('post_author', $product->get_id());
    $author  = get_user_by('id', $seller);
    $vendor = dokan()->vendor->get($seller);
    $store_info = dokan_get_store_info($author->ID);
    
    if (!empty($store_info['store_name'])) {
        return sprintf( '<span class="vendorpage"><a href=" %s">in this store %s</a></span>', $vendor->get_shop_url(), $vendor->get_shop_name() );
    }
    // Nothing found; return an empty string.
    return '';
}
```

Comment: thanks for your time. But I received syntax error. I fixed syntax errors but this time store url is wrong . I get url like this https://webisite.com/index.php/product/product-name/%

Comment: Ah yes. I've updated my answer, which should fix the syntax error.

Comment: Really thank you very much. I could not solve this problem in myself